# Use R with Google Colaboratory

Tags: r, google-colaboratory

Is it possible to integrate google colaboratory as a library with R? I would like to use it alongside an RMarkdown Report.

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-r-in-google-colab-b6e02d736497

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't what I'm looking for. I wanted to use colab on a local instance of R using RStudio.